# Using Custom Compact layout on Visualforce Page

Tags: visualforce, javascript

I have a visual force page displaying lots of information in a report of sorts. To enchance the user experience I have added some code to load the standard compact layout for records to provide some additional information. This is done with the following code. LookupHoverDetail.getHover is functionality provide by Salesforce.

```
<a href="#" id="{!rec.Id}"
  onmouseover="LookupHoverDetail.getHover('{!rec.Id}', '/{!rec.Id}/m?retURL=/{!rec.Id}&isAjaxRequest=1').show();"
  onmouseout="LookupHoverDetail.getHover('{!red.Id}').hide();">
    <apex:outputtext value="{!rec.Name}"/>
</a>
```

However, this only loads the System Default compact layout. It does it quite nicely, but I have a custom compact layout with more relevant information. How can I get that to display?

Comment: Did you manage to use Compact Layout in Visualforce Page ?

Answer (score 0):

So the code above was actually bringing up a "mini" layout. Not a "compact" payout. Answer is, know your mini-vs-compact layouts.

Comment: And how do you get the Compact layout?